# Select grouped by two columns with Count

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having problems trying to understand how to build this query.

My data scheme:

```
id category name        userid
1  sports   football    1
2  cars     ferrari     1
3  sports   basketball  1
4  film     Matrix      9
5  film     Fauno       9
6  sports   Surf        3
```

As you can see the *category* can be repeated even for a same user id because the *name* field is different. So my idea is to **get the categories of a set of users** and **the amount of users for each categories on that set**.

Lets say i have the set of user set_of_user = (1,9,3), If i run the query

```
SELECT something FROM category_table WHERE userid IN set_of_user SOME CONDITION HERE
```

The correct result should be:

```
category: sports
users: 2
category: cars
users: 1
category: film
users: 1
```

My best shot was:

```
SELECT userid, category, COUNT(userid) as users from interests WHERE `userid` in ' . $norm_info_ids . ' GROUP BY category
```

But this gave a bad result, how can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for using `COUNT` with `DISTINCT`, along with `GROUP BY`:

```
select category, count(distinct userid)
from interests
where userid in (1,3,9)
group by category
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89250/2)

Resulting in:

```
CATEGORY   COUNT(DISTINCT USERID)
cars       1
film       1
sports     2
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to select the distinct paring of category and user id

```
select t.category, count(t.user_id)
from
(
 SELECT distinct category,user_id 
 from tab
 where user_id in (1,3,9)
 ) t
 group by t.category
```